# Physical meaning of dividing the mean square by variance of a distribution

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions

In the field of chromatography, the so-called "efficiency" a Gaussian peak or at times an exponentially modified Gaussian peak is expressed as the mean squared divided by the variance of the peak. The higher the efficiency, the better the separation of mixtures.

https://www.shimadzu.com/an/hplc/support/lib/lctalk/theoretical_plate.html

Can we associate a physical meaning to the quantity which is obtained by dividing the mean of a distribution and divided by its variance? Is this measure common in other fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a way of quantifying signal/noise, except squared - I haven't used it like that, but every field comes up with its own conventions of how to talk about the quality of data, depending also on what those data typically look like ...

Comment: Michael, I can confirm that this has nothing to do with signal to noise. In signal to noise theory as used in chem, variance is that of the signal magnitude. In chromatography, the variance is that of the distribution itself in time. The efficiency indicates, how narrow the peak is. Smaller the variance, larger the value of efficiency. When the peaks are narrow, a lot of component peaks can be separated and distinguished within a given time window.

Comment: Ah, interesting - so one even has to distinguish between different notions of variance here. But what kind of answer are you expecting beyond the explanation you have just given yourself in your comment? I guess the variance will have something to do with a diffusion coefficient on chromatography paper ... but we're supposed to be discussing mathematics here ...

Comment: I was wondering if this type of metric = (mean)^2/variance is used is other fields or not. It seems this is unique to chromatography.

Comment: mean/variance is the [Fano factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_factor) of a probability distribution

Comment: Interesting. Fano factor seems to be just the inverse of the so-called efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In actuarial sciences, a Bayesian theory called "credibility theory" uses some kind of metrics that looks like mean^2/var.

The goal of this theory is to give a balance between individual info and global info using bayesian concepts. Using the conditional variance decomposition, the so-called bulhman credibility factor can be expressed as the square of the conditional mean divided by the unconditional variance.

Surprisingly, the Wikipedia page is quite good on this (very specific) topic. See there : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BChlmann_model

If you have unconditional data, the formula is the one you are seeking and gives a credibility to individual info against global info : is this line in my data "in the middle" of the data, or is it too much of an outlier ?

In this sense, it looks like the same idea as your "concentration" interpretation through "efficiency of a peak".